# GenerationType.AUTO vs GenerationType.IDENTITY in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

Currently, we are using MySQL as a database and we use

`@Generated Value(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

It's working perfectly in certain situations we need to migrate our database to Oracle at that time it's not working properly. If anyone knows what's the actual difference is present behind this and how it's working?

Comment: what ORM provider you are using?

Comment: If you use `GenerationType.AUTO` then by default hibernate uses `hibernate_sequence`  for the sequence which is used by  all tables and only one sequence value can be consumed at a time which means if sequence 1 is used then it can not be used anywhere else. But with `GenerationType.IDENTITY` the ids are only unique for that particular column. (Test DB - MySQL)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How could it "work properly" (you don't define basic info like what you mean by that) with Oracle ? I don't see the relevance of `AUTO` to your question - that simply lets an implementation choose what it wants to use.

"`IDENTITY`" (as per JPA javadocs and spec - what you should be referring to) means *autoincrement*. There is no such concept in Oracle, yet there is in MySQL, SQLServer and a few others. I would expect any decent JPA implementation to flag an error when even trying such a thing.

Oracle would allow "`SEQUENCE`", or "`TABLE`" strategies to be used however

Comment: yes,As you said there is no Auto increment option in oracle.but if i use GenerationType.AUTO the model is working for oracle database because if i give Auto the JPA automatically taken the generated type according to the database.thanks for your clarification.

Comment: Hi, I think it would be better just to answer the question than to tease the guy asking something. There is no such concept as auto_increment.... well then explain what identity means and why it can't work with Oracle, right?

Answer (score 31):

Quoting [Java Persistence/Identity and Sequencing](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing):

> **Identity** sequencing uses **special IDENTITY columns** in the database to allow the database to automatically assign an id to the object when its row is inserted. Identity columns are supported in many databases, such as **MySQL, DB2, SQL Server, Sybase and Postgres**. Oracle does not support IDENTITY columns but they can be simulated through using sequence objects and triggers.

so I prefer to use **SEQUENCE** instead

> Sequence objects use special database objects to generate ids. Sequence objects are only supported in some databases, such as Oracle, DB2, and Postgres. Usually, a SEQUENCE object has a name, an INCREMENT, and other database object settings. Each time the .NEXTVAL is selected the sequence is incremented by the INCREMENT.

Example :

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="EMP_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="EMP_SEQ", sequenceName="EMP_SEQ", allocationSize=100)
    private long id;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Im using JPA and Oracle 11g, the solution that worked for me is the following

```
package com.example.springsocial.model;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

@Entity
@Table(name = "rol", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "name")
})
public class Rol {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="rol_sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="rol_sequence", sequenceName="rol_sequence", allocationSize=100)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    private Date createdAt;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Date updatedAt;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Integer createdBy;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Integer updatedBy;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public Integer getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(Integer createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Integer getUpdatedBy() {
        return updatedBy;
    }

    public void setUpdatedBy(Integer updatedBy) {
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
    }
}
```