# Spring Boot project fails to run because of Schema-validation: missing sequence [hibernate_sequence]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

When I try to run a Spring Boot and Hibernate application, I am finding that it is falling over because of:

`org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing sequence [hibernate_sequence]`

But I cannot see why this is because I am not using Hibernate sequences. My tables, in Apache Derby, are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE TEAM (
  TEAM_ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),    
  NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,    
  CONSTRAINT PK_TEAM PRIMARY KEY(Team_Id)
);

CREATE TABLE PLAYER (
  PLAYER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),    
  NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,  
  NUM INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  POSITION VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,    
  TEAM_ID INTEGER, 
  CONSTRAINT PK_PLAYER PRIMARY KEY(PLAYER_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_PLAYER FOREIGN KEY(TEAM_ID) REFERENCES TEAM(TEAM_ID)
);
```

My application's `application.properties` file is:

```
# Hibernate table generation.
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true    

# Apache Derby settings
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Library
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password`
```

And the two Java classes involved are:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEAM")
public class Team {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TEAM_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer teamId;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            mappedBy = "team")
    private List<Player> players;
```

And:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PLAYER")
public class Player {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PLAYER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer playerId;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "NUM")
    private int num;

    @Column(name = "POSITION")
    private String position;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TEAM_ID", nullable = true)
    private Team team;
```

Can anyone advise where I am wrong?

Maven dependencies are:

```
<dependencies>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
            <version>10.14.2.0</version>
        </dependency>      
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Do your DB has sequence name with `hibernate_sequence` ?

Comment: No, There is nothing by this name at all. When I've used Hibernate/JPA I have never needed this.

Comment: Can you please try `create sequence <schema>.hibernate_sequence` and see the result

Comment: Where/how do I create this?

Comment: In your DB. Follow the link for creating a sequence in Derby. https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/rrefsqljcreatesequence.html

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking at that now, and also using IDENTITY which does not need sequences.

Comment: @Amit Bera: If you want to convert your comments to an answer, I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: Morgan I have added it as an answer. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are facing the issue as there is a missing sequence `hibernate_sequence`. You can create the sequence manually on your DB using `create sequence <schema>.hibernate_sequence`. For more info about creating a sequence in `Derby`  please follow the [link](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/rrefsqljcreatesequence.html).

Comment: An alternative approach is to declare the tables with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`. This removes the need for sequences.

Answer (score 11):

Hit this issue and below is my searching results:

1. If you use `GenerationType.AUTO` in your java bean, then by default hibernate uses `hibernate_sequence` for the sequence.

   So one option is to create this sequence in the DB by:

   `create sequence <schema>.hibernate_sequence`
2. or you can use `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` instead in your java bean source code, which does not require such sequence.

   Quoting Java Persistence/Identity:

   > Identity sequencing uses special IDENTITY columns in the database to
   >   allow the database to automatically assign an id to the object when
   >   its row is inserted. Identity columns are supported in many databases,
   >   such as MySQL, DB2, SQL Server, Sybase and Postgres. Oracle does not
   >   support IDENTITY columns but they can be simulated through using
   >   sequence objects and triggers.

Further reading:

[GenerationType.AUTO vs GenerationType.IDENTITY in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096466/generationtype-auto-vs-generationtype-identity-in-hibernate)