# Hibernate Many-To-Many Association using JOIN-Table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, associations, hibernate-mapping

I am finding it difficult to understand hibernate Many-To-Many association using join table .

I got sample project from net .
It includes

Course.java

```
package com.chad.model;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="chad_course")
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade={CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(name="course_student",
               joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="course_id"),
               inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="student_id"))
    private List<Student> studentList;

    public Course()
    {

    }

    public Course( String title) {
        this.title = title; 
    }




    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }


    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public List<Student> getStudentList() {
        return studentList;
    }

    public void setStudentList(List<Student> studentList) {
        this.studentList = studentList;
    }


}
```

**Student.java**

```
package com.chad.model;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Chad_student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="EMAIL_ID")
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade={CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(name="course_student",
                joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="student_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="course_id"))
    private List<Course> courseList;

    public Student(){}

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


}
```

> 1) My doubt was , The example that i got from internet has

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade={CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST})
        @JoinTable(name="course_student",
                    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="student_id"),
                    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="course_id"))
```

the above block written in both entity classes .
But in some other articles they have written 
the same block in one entity class.
and in another entity class only @ManyToMany --> with no joinColumn

Can i know the importance of both syntax ??

> 2)  After running the program i got the following logs

**Main.java**

```
Course course = new Course("Photography");

        session.save(course);

        Student student1 = new Student("John", "Dao", "john@gmail.com");
        Student student2 = new Student("John1", "Dao1", "john1@gmail1.com");


        List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        studentList.add(student1);
        studentList.add(student2);

        course.setStudentList(studentList);

        session.save(student1);
        session.save(student2);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
```

**LOGS**

```
Hibernate: insert into chad_course (title, instructor_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Chad_student (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Chad_student (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into course_student (course_id, student_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into course_student (course_id, student_id) values (?, ?)
```

Now

- 1st insert is into chad_course . **correct**
- 2nd & 3rd insert is into Chad_student  . **correct**
- 4th & 5th insert is into course_student --> how does hibernate know
  what course_id and student_id to insert , since there is no    select
  query happening .

Answer (score 0):

GenerationType.IDENTITY used with DBs where auto-increment is supported like MySQL,SQLServer and few others, this is not available across all DBs like Oracle etc.

This is the reason you don't see any Select SQL query being fired

Check - [GenerationType.AUTO vs GenerationType.IDENTITY in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096466/generationtype-auto-vs-generationtype-identity-in-hibernate)