# JPA DDL generation exception

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have the following entity

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Entity
@Table(name = "REF_CLIENT")
@IdClass(RefClientID.class)

@NamedNativeQueries({@NamedNativeQuery(name = "RefClient.updateByClicincli", query = "UPDATE REF_CLIENT rc "
        + "SET rc.clicexcli = :clicexcli , rc.cliidclient=:cliidclient ,"
        + "rc.cliemail=:cliemail, rc.clitypcli=:clitypcli ," + "rc.clietatcli=:clietatcli"
        + "  WHERE rc.clicincli = :clicincli ;")})
public class RefClient extends CommonData implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4763218211813908401L;

    /**
     * N X NUMBER Code interne client
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CLICINCLI", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long clicincli;

    /**
     * N X VARCHAR2(13) Code externe client
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(name = "CLICEXCLI", unique = true, length = 13, nullable = false)
    private String clicexcli;
```

the ID class is as below

```
@Data
public class RefClientID implements Serializable  {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1932584805198196159L;

    /**
     * N X VARCHAR2(13) Code externe client
     */
    private String clicexcli;

    /**
     * N X NUMBER Code interne client
     */
    private Long clicincli;

}
```

the generated DDL in the logs is

> Hibernate: create table ref_client (clicexcli varchar(13) not null auto_increment, clicincli bigint not null, datcre DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE not null

as you see VARCHAR can't be auto-incremented how to fix this ?

I tried removing the identity strategy, the ddl is working fine but without auto_increment for the clicincli, if I reuse it it will generate the auto_increment in the String field clicexcli and there will be no auto_increment in the Long one (clicincli)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since default *strategy* for ID generation in **@GeneratedValue** annotation is **GenerationType.AUTO**, we have to manualy change it to **SEQUENCE** when we use generators.

I'd change your code to :

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(name = "CLICEXCLI", unique = true, length = 13, nullable = false)
    private String clicexcli;
```

You can check it in [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html)

> Default: javax.persistence.GenerationType.AUTO

Comment: I have always the autoincrement added to ddl, not working :(

Comment: I am not talking about AUTOINCREMENT but rather, strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE isn't that really working ?

Comment: Hibernate: create table ref_client (clicexcli varchar(13) not null auto_increment, clicincli bigint not null,

yes is really not working :(

Comment: the auto_increment should be generated on clicincli but it's not and being generated on clicexcli

that what I can't understand !!! I tried removing the long id and it working fine , but adding it will generate this issue

Comment: A lot depends on your database https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096466/generationtype-auto-vs-generationtype-identity-in-hibernate

Comment: I have mysql database

Comment: About mysql and its problem with JPA https://vladmihalcea.com/why-should-not-use-the-auto-jpa-generationtype-with-mysql-and-hibernate/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182203/discussion-between-mohammed-housseyn-taleb-and-emil-hotkowski).