# Sequence Strategy for MYSQL not working (EclipseLink, Glassfish)

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink

Sequence Strategy for MYSQL not working

I have an Id defined in my entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

When persisting an entity I get the following error. I checked several hints, but noone worked for me.

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="SEQUENCE" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")
```

MYSQL Version : 8

SQL "UPDATE SEQUENCE ..." can be executed from the workbench without problems. "OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT" seems not to be valid.

I guess "OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT" is coming implicitely when .persist() is called, because of the sequence strategie.

Any help hints ?

***UPDATE***

Switching to 
strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
does not invoke "OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT" and it works fine. Strange.

Comment: MySQL version? Where is 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT' coming from? Wherever it is, it isn't valid for MySQL.

Comment: AUTO means let the JPA provider do whatever the heck they want. SEQUENCE means use a datastore sequence. Leave it as AUTO and you get no predictable behaviour

Comment: Auto uses table sequencing, which is why you see just a "UPDATE" sql statement, and the "SQL_SELECT_LIMIT" option isn't something the EclipseLink MySQLPlatform class adds, so it might be a driver setting.  This should be looked into as it might affect your other queries - show the full stack trace, and make sure you haven't added any native settings somehow.

Comment: Maybe this link helps :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096466/generationtype-auto-vs-generationtype-identity-in-hibernate