# Auto generated id is generated based on previous JpaRepository.save()

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have two entity class:

```java
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    
    // getter and setter
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class B {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    
    // getter and setter
}
```

I have the repositories which extends `JpaRepository`.

```java
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
aRepo.save(a); // generates id = 1
bRepo.save(b); // generates id = 2
```

Since I am inserting to different tables, I would like the ids to be generated based on the previous id in that particular table and not depending on the previous insertion in some other table. Is there any way to do this?

I am using MySQL as my db.

Comment: I think it could help you: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-identifiers

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is `GenerationType.IDENTITY`.

[GenerationType.AUTO vs GenerationType.IDENTITY in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096466/generationtype-auto-vs-generationtype-identity-in-hibernate) may help you